# Question about a family of nested countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, order-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote a family of countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, such that for each $U, V\in\mathcal{F}$ we have that $U\subseteq V$, or $V\subseteq U$. Let $(\mathcal{F}, \preceq)$ denote the inclusion partial order of $\mathcal{F}$.

1. Is it true that $(\mathcal{F}, \preceq)$ is isomorphic to $(S, \leq)$ where $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?
2. Is it true that $\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{F}}U$ is a countable set?

Comment: How about Dedekind cuts in $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Thank You, I have changed the question.

Comment: Still no. Fix a well order $\prec$ of type $\omega_1$ on a subset of $\mathbb R$, and let $\mathcal F$ consist of proper initial segments of $\prec$.

Comment: And what about the question 2?

Comment: Emil's second comment also answers question 2.

Comment: The questions are equivalent, anyway: $\bigcup\mathcal F$ is countable iff $(\mathcal F,\subseteq)$ embeds in $(\mathbb R,\le)$ iff $(\mathcal F,\subseteq)$ has countable cofinality.

Comment: Thank You I understand the unswers. Do You mind if I delete this question?

Comment: I'd rather you not delete the question, because Emil's comments can be useful for other readers.

Comment: Just to complement the previous answers, if $\mathcal{F}$ is maximal for the given properties (such $\mathcal{F}$ exists by Zorn) then $V=\bigcup\mathcal{F}$ can't be countable, since otherwise the new family $\mathcal{F}\cup\{V\}$ contradicts maximality. This directly solves 2 without transiting through 1 (but indeed 1 is easy to derive, by the previously given cofinality argument).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek why not post an answer explicating the argument of your comment?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins All right, done.

Comment: See here for a model (without choice) in which a union of a chain of countable sets of reals is always countable: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4423643/210610

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\let\sset\subseteq\def\cF{\mathcal F}\def\R{\mathbb R}\def\Q{\mathbb Q}$The answer to both questions is negative: let $\preceq$ be a well order of type $\omega_1$ on a subset of $\R$, and let $\cF$ consist of all proper initial segments of $\preceq$. Then $\cF$ is a family of countable sets totally ordered by $\subseteq$, but $\bigcup\cF$ is uncountable, and $(\cF,{\sset})$ does not embed in $(\R,{\le})$ as $(\omega_1,{\le})$ does not embed there.

In fact, for any $\cF$ as in the question, the following are equivalent:

1. $(\cF,{\sset})$ embeds in $(\R,{\le})$.
2. $\bigcup\cF$ is countable.
3. $(\cF,{\sset})$ has countable cofinality.

1 → 3: Any subset of $\R$ has a countable cofinal subset.

3 → 2: If $C\sset\cF$ is a cofinal countable subset, then $\bigcup\cF=\bigcup C$ is a countable union of countable sets, hence countable.

2 → 1: Let $I=\bigcup\cF$. Then $\{(x,y):\forall U\in\cF\,(y\in U\to x\in U)\}$ is a total preorder on $I$, hence it includes a total order $\preceq$ on $I$, and every $U\in\cF$ is an initial segment of $\preceq$. Since the lexicographic product $(I,{\preceq})\times2$ embeds in $(\Q,{\le})$, we can find an embedding $f\colon(I,{\preceq})\to(\Q,{\le})$ such that $f(x)>\sup\{f(y):y\prec x\}$ for all $x\in I$. Then $U\mapsto\sup f[U]$ is an embedding of $(\cF,{\sset})$ in $(\R,{\le})$.

Note that the example in the beginning is, in a sense, the worst that can happen: as any total order, $(\cF,{\sset})$ has a well-ordered cofinal subset $C$. If $C$ is not countable, it can only have order type $\omega_1$, as otherwise some element of $\cF$ is uncountable. Thus, $(\cF,{\sset})$ has cofinality $\omega_1$, $|\bigcup\cF|=\aleph_1$, and using a similar argument as above, $(\cF,{\sset})$ embeds in the long line $\omega_1\times[0,1)$.